# Azure Dev Ops Build Parameter to define BuildNumber?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a git repo, with a `master` branch that we take `feature\myFeature` from, work on, and then raise pull requests back to `master` .. quite straight forward.

When a `feature` branch is pushed up to the git repo, we have a build process which runs on that branch, and produces a build. It takes the semver info major.minor.patch from the assembly of the project..

What i want to do though, is (depending on if the build is on `feature` or `master`) change the construction of the build name..

something like:

- `feature` --> 1.0.3-alpha1, 1.0.3-alpha2, 1.0.3-alpha3
- `master` --> 1.0.3-rc1, 1.0.3-rc2

the challenge that i have right now is that the number on the end, derived from using $(Rev:r) does not seem to be able to be used in the PowerShell task i have written to work out the build number...

I have tried to do a little testing around setting a buildnumber things such as:

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleaseType]alpha")
```

and then doing...

```
$(ReleaseType)$(Rev:.r)
```

seems to 'lock' the release name to whatever original value there is for ReleaseType var..

another option i have tried is:

```
Write-Output ("##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]"-alpha")
```

but this just overwrites whatever is in the options table Build number format box...

Is what i am trying to do possible? An alternative i guess would be to have a different build process for each branch type.. seems a bit OTT.. is there any way to derive the $(Rev:.r) from PowerShell?

Comment: I don't know if it will help but I use to update the build number with short hash and branch name `Write-Host("##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER" + "_" + $env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION.Substring(0,9) + "+" + $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME)`

Comment: And you could test the value of `$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` to see if it's `master` or another branch before updating the build number...

Comment: I'll post up with my current solution later today :)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use the token `$(Rev:.r)` in PowerShell.

If you just want to change the construction of the build name something like:

- `feature` --> 1.0.3-alpha1, 1.0.3-alpha2, 1.0.3-alpha3
- `master` --> 1.0.3-rc1, 1.0.3-rc2

Then you can create two CI build pipelines (one for `feature` and another for `master`) and set the `Build number format` directly like this:

- `feature` --> `1.0.3-alpha$(rev:.r)`
- `master` --> `1.0.3-rc$(rev:.r)`

Based on your description you may use the semver info `major.minor.patch` from the assembly of the project as part (prefix) of the build number. In this case the token `$(rev:.r)` is not incremental as the prefix always changing, So the value of `$(rev:.r)` will always be `1`. Please see [Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#tokens) for details.

> Use $(Rev:.r) to ensure that every completed build has a unique name.
>   When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has
>   changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer Andy, I ended up coming to the same conclusion about requiring multiple pipelines.. for clarity, I want to do my work and set the assembly to x.y.z and then increment multiple 'versions' of that same build I.e. x.y.z-prerelease1, oops found a bug x.y.z-prerelease2 ... Interestingly is there 'simple' way to read assembly version? Currently I use regex, and string manipulation, to then update build.updatebuildnumber

Comment: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion is a tool that could help you manage assembly version when using git...